# Problems with inserting user into sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wanted to do a simple login and signup page, yet everytime i try to log a user, it tells me it couldn't do the query. I use mariadb servers.

This is the inserting

```
$sql="INSERT INTO userid  VALUES ( {$_POST['usname']} , {$_POST['firstname']} , {$_POST['lastname']} , {$_POST['wordpass']} , '' )";
```

and this is the login part

```
    <form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="uname">Choose an Username: </label>
            <input type="text" id="uname" name="usname" pattern="[a-z]{3-15}" placeholder="Username">
            <div class="tinytext"> Username must be at least 3 characters long and at most 15 characters long, containing only lowercase letters </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="fname"> Enter First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" pattern="[a-z]{3-15}" placeholder="First Name">
            <div class="tinytext"> First Name must be at least 3 characters long and at most 15 characters long, containing only lowercase letters</div>        
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lname"> Enter Last Name Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="lastname" pattern="[a-z]{3-15}" placeholder="Last Name">
            <div class="tinytext"> Last Name must be at least 3 characters long and at most 15 characters long, containing only lowercase letters</div>     
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pwd"> Enter Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="pwd" name="wordpass" minlenght="8" maxlenght="30" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="tinytext"> Password must be at least 8 characters long and at most 30 characters long</div>     
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="window.location.href='thankyou.php'">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Remove the `onclick` on your button and replace it with `type="submit"`. This will submit your form correctly. Is the database name `userid` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your Form-Problem, also your SQL is going to translate into a wrong SQL statement.

lets assume:

```
usname = myusername
firstname = myfirstname
lastname = mylastname
wordpass = mypass
```

will translate to:

```
INSERT INTO userid  VALUES (myusername, myfirstname, mylastname, mypass, '')
```

Where all your values are not strings and will result in an SQL error! Should be:

```
INSERT INTO userid  VALUES ('myusername', 'myfirstname', 'mylastname', 'mypass', '')
```

This for your error

BUUUT, you should read about SQL-INJECTION, because that is what you will get if you are sending this directly to the DB!

Example for Prepared Statement(using PDO)

```
<?php
// open new PDO connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

// prepare your data
$data = [
  'username' => $_POST['usname']
  'firstname' => $_POST['firstname']
  'lastname' => $_POST['lastname']
  'password' => $_POST['wordpass']
];

// create prepared statement to prevent SQL-injection
$sql = "INSERT INTO userid (username, firstname, lastname, password) VALUES (:username, :firstname, :lastname, :password)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// execute statement and persist to DB
$stmt->execute($data);
```

other examples can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: You are right, but please provide an example with the prepared statements!

Comment: @MeesEgberts me? there are lots of examples for prepared statements out there ;)

Comment: and after all its the OP's decision wheter using it or not. Its his DB that is going to be vulnerable to SQL-injection. I just pointed him in the right direction.

Comment: @braun_lukas, you're right. There are plenty of examples out there, but the problem is if people see bad code in an answer, especially an accepted answer, there is the risk that they will consider it to be good code, this propagates the use of dangerous code.

Comment: @MeesEgberts you're right too ;) the problem is that you cannot put everything in answer. the above code is also "not that good". its lacking a try catch, validation of the posted data etc etc

Comment: Much better! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a small problem in your form you have to make it submit button instead of just a simple button.

Because untill the form will not be submitted the values will also not be accessible by your `thankyou.php`

Your button should be like this

```
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

And your full code be like this-

```
    <form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="uname">Choose an Username: </label>
            <input type="text" id="uname" name="usname" pattern="[a-z]{3-15}" placeholder="Username">
            <div class="tinytext"> Username must be at least 3 characters long and at most 15 characters long, containing only lowercase letters </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="fname"> Enter First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" pattern="[a-z]{3-15}" placeholder="First Name">
            <div class="tinytext"> First Name must be at least 3 characters long and at most 15 characters long, containing only lowercase letters</div>        
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lname"> Enter Last Name Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="lastname" pattern="[a-z]{3-15}" placeholder="Last Name">
            <div class="tinytext"> Last Name must be at least 3 characters long and at most 15 characters long, containing only lowercase letters</div>     
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pwd"> Enter Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="pwd" name="wordpass" minlenght="8" maxlenght="30" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="tinytext"> Password must be at least 8 characters long and at most 30 characters long</div>     
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: This seems the correct answer. Otherwise, there's something wrong with the query and then we need to see the table.

Comment: Yes. I can be a problem in the query also

Comment: The code for the table is ```CREATE TABLE userid { username varchar(15), firstname varchar(15), lastname varchar(15), notes text};```

Comment: You are taking password also from user don't you have column for that

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE userid { username varchar(15), firstname varchar(15), lastname varchar(15), password varchar(30), notes text};``` still doesnt work